# Conditional formatting to change color of Symbol

Tags: excel

I want to change the color of symbols within a column using conditional formatting as illustrated in the attached spreadsheet snippet. The up and down arrows are represented using `=UNICHAR (number)` expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unichar symbols are difficult to evaluate in Conditional Formatting formulas. Instead of Unichar() try using a font like Wingdings or Marlett in the cells and set the cell value to the character that creates the symbol in that font.

Then you can easily use Conditional Formatting to evaluate the underlying cell character. For example, the characters `t` and `u` in Marlett font show up / down arrows.

Here is a screenshot. All the Unichar characters evaluate to code 63, so no CF difference there. But the cells formatted with Marlett have rules that check for the letters t and u.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `UNICHAR` reverse function is `UNICODE`- so you can use that in conditional formatting.

For red color:

```
=UNICODE(A1)=11167
```

For green color:

```
=UNICODE(A1)=11165
```

[image]

Comment: Can i have your excel file shown above... i use the same but not ok with me...